# css serial transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, autogrow

Im browsing the net for more than a day now and still can't find a working solution to the followin problem.

1. A div should grow from nothing to 100% from the bottom up then
2. text should fade in
3. then a timeout
4. then text should fade-out
5. then div should schrink towards the bottom of the div and vanish.

---

```
.max{
  max-height:100%;height:100%;color:#fff;
  -moz-transition-property:max-height,height, color;
  -moz-transition-duration:3s,3s,1s;
  -moz-transition-delay:0s,0s,2s;
 }
.min{
  max-height:0%;height:0%;color:transparent;
  -moz-transition-property:max-height,height, color;
  -moz-transition-duration:3s,3s,1s;
  -moz-transition-delay:1s,1s,0s;
 }
```

---

how can I serialize max & min into one CssClass
If that's not possible how to do it in another way.
But that doesn't fly.
Anyone a nice idea or experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition can only work, if your start values and your end values differ.

Because your start values and end values don't differ (*'you come from nothing and you go to nothing' (Always look on the bright side of life)*) it is not possible in one CSS class.

What maybe possible is that you have two classes say `appear` and `disappear` and switch between them after a certain amount of time with javascript (`setTimeout` function)

Comment: I had hopes there was somesort of startrender command I could use inbetween or something that triggered the rendering. The Javascript I already tried that but couldn't get it to work (I'm not a java wiz)

Comment: Do you use any JavaScript Library as mootools, jquery, dojo, etc?

Comment: Nope never could make a choice/had the time to go indepth. Using my Own library for 10 years now.

Comment: Yunzen, it seems if I want 'LibraryLess' your answer is the most helpfull. Thanks